# Using pthread to have one thread do all disk writing that other threads send it?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, io, pthreads

I am right now trying to create a program where multiple threads are querying for data that needs to be processed and then written to disk. Currently I am using pragma and pragma critical in order to ensure that the data is being written to as intended.

This is quite costly though as threads are having to wait for one another. I read that it should be possible to have a single thread handle all write to disks for you while the others can focus on getting the incoming data and parsing it. How would I go about doing this?

The program is an XDP-based packet parser than only stores particular information regarding each packet. The code is based upon this project code here: https://github.com/xdp-project/xdp-tutorial/blob/master/tracing04-xdp-tcpdump/xdp_sample_pkts_user.c

```
    static int print_bpf_output(void *data, int size)
    {
        struct {
            __u16 cookie;
            __u16 pkt_len;
            __u8  pkt_data[SAMPLE_SIZE];
        } __packed *e = data;
        struct pcap_pkthdr h = {
            .caplen = SAMPLE_SIZE,
            .len    = e->pkt_len,
        };
        struct timespec ts;
        int i, err;

        if (e->cookie != 0xdead) {
            printf("BUG cookie %x sized %d\n",
                   e->cookie, size);
            return LIBBPF_PERF_EVENT_ERROR;
        }

        err = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
        if (err < 0) {
            printf("Error with gettimeofday! (%i)\n", err);
            return LIBBPF_PERF_EVENT_ERROR;
        }

        h.ts.tv_sec  = ts.tv_sec;
        h.ts.tv_usec = ts.tv_nsec / NANOSECS_PER_USEC;

        if (verbose) {
            printf("pkt len: %-5d bytes. hdr: ", e->pkt_len);
            for (i = 0; i < e->pkt_len; i++)
                printf("%02x ", e->pkt_data[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }

        pcap_dump((u_char *) pdumper, &h, e->pkt_data);
        pcap_pkts++;
        return LIBBPF_PERF_EVENT_CONT;
    }
```

This function would be called by numerous threads, and I want the pcap_dump calls to be executed by a single, different thread.

Comment: this is too broad .. completely depends on the architecture of your program and what it needs to do. Any time you have multiple threads accessing the same data, those accesses will need to be synchronized or you will have race conditions.

Comment: I have edited the question add more specificity, including a link to the code in question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,that is a common way to avoid delays where the disk is fast enough to handle the average data rate, but where occasional data peaks, disk cache writes, directory updates and other such cause intermittent data loss.

You need a producer-consumer queue.  Such a class or code/struct, using condvars or semaphores,is easily found on SO or elsewhere on the net.  The queue only needs to queue up pointers.

Don't use a wide queue to queue up the bulk data.  As soon as it is read from [wherever],   read it in to a malloced buffer/struct that has the data, path, command and anything else that the write thread might need to perform the write.  Queue up the struct pointer to the write thread.  In the write thread, loop round the P-C queue pop, get the pointers, do the write, (or whatever is commanded by the struct command field), and,if no error, free the struct.  If there is some problem, you could load an error message into some field of the struct and queue it off again to some error-logging thread, store it in a queue to try again later, whatever you want, really.

This way, you insulate the rest of your app from those unavoidable, occasional disk delays.  That is very important with high-latency disks, eg. those on a network.  It also makes housekeeping operations much easier, for instance, some hour timer could queue up a struct whose command field instructs the thread to open a new file with a date-time stamp in the filename, so making it easier to track the data later without wading through one, massive, file:)  Such operations, without the queue and write thread, would surely inflict a massive delay to your app:(